# how to disable rx-checksumming in a Virtualbox's vm?

Tags: virtualbox, ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I am trying to attach an XDP BPF byte object to my interface in a Virtualbox vm. But I encountered these error message:

```
Error: virtio_net: Can't set XDP while host is implementing GRO_HW/CSUM, disable GRO_HW/CSUM first
```

My Vm's NIC:
[my vm's NIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZTHQ.png)

I'd run the following commands on the vm and also on my host machine:

```
sudo ethtool -K wlp2s0 rx off tx off tso off gso off
```

In the host, there was no error. But in the vm, the `rx-checksum` won't get turned off and it will show this:

```
Actual Changes:
rx-checksum: on [requested off]
```

Comment: Wasn't changing for the host enough? That's what the first error message seems to imply.

Comment: No that doesn't work

Comment: Then, I don't think you have many options. You can try a newer guest kernel (maybe it's now possible to disable that) or you can switch to a different driver.